# How can I project a rectangular texture into a region of curved shape?

Tags: image-processing, graphics, textures, texture-mapping

I want to map a texture image of rectangular shape into a curved area. The curved area has a axis defined by bezier curve and fixed width.

I can map the points on the axis to the texture by percentile, and get a stripe of pixels to fill the region. But this way the left side of the region is "stretched", and I get unfilled gaps.

[image]

How can I map the texture to the curved area "smoothly"? Is there an algorithm for such a task?

Comment: I think OpenGL/DirectX should handle this very well. Graphics chip does the texture mapping by hardware so it's pretty fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

My own naive solution is to fill the gaps(trianglar area in the image) with pixel values by interpolating between the adjacent points on normal vectors.

Later I found a more mathematical solution to this problem in a paper:

http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~sczhu/papers/Conf_2011/portrait-painting-preprint.pdf

It map the grids of the rectanglar texture to the spline-shaped area with a method called thin-plate spline (TPS) transformation:

> we compute a thin-plate spline (TPS) transformation [Barrodale
>   et al. 1993] between the pairs of source and target dot positions
>   (e.g., between the corresponding backbone control points in Figs.4a
>   and 4b), and apply the transformation to the vertices of a quadrilateral
>   mesh covering the source brush stroke to get the deformed
>   mesh. Finally, we compute a texture mapping using the mesh, with
>   a bilinear interpolation inside each quadrilateral.

I am thinking maybe the same transformation can be done with bezier curves.

Hope this is helpful.